Error getting data from firestore: _TypeError(type Future<List> is not a subtype of type List in type cast
I’m having trouble getting a List<Event> to display in the Calendar I’m developing. Despite calling it from Firestore, I’m not able to retrieve the list of events. I suspect the issue may be related to how I’ve written the Controller.
models.dart
class Event {
  final String Id;
  final String user;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String? type;
  final DateTime from;
  final DateTime to;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  Event({
    required this.Id,
    required this.user,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    this.type,
    required this.from,
    required this.to,
    this.backgroundColor = pinkColor,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> ToMap() {
    return {
      "Id": Id,
      "user": user,
      "title": title,
      "description": description,
      "type": type,
      "from": from,
      "to": to,
    };
  }

  factory Event.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, String documentId) {
    return Event(
        Id: documentId,
        user: map["user"] as String,
        title: map["title"] as String,
        description: map["description"] as String,
        type: map["TYPE"] as String,
        from: map["from"],
        to: map["to"]);
  }
}

database.dart
class Database {


  Future GetEvents(String user) async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(ApiPath.Event())
        .where("email", isEqualTo: user)
        .snapshots();
  }
}

controller.dart
class EventController {
  String currentuser = Auth().getCurrentUserEmail();


  Future<List<Event>> GetEventsController() async {
    List<Event> events = [];
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> data = await Database().GetEvents(currentuser);
    data.listen((QuerySnapshot e) {
      for (DocumentSnapshot doc in e.docs) {
        Map<String, dynamic> map = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        Event newevent = Event.fromMap(map, map["id"]);
        events.add(newevent);
      }
    });
    return events;
  }

Calender.dart
class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Calendar({super.key});

  @override
  State<Calendar> createState() => _CalendarState();
}

class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  
  _data() {
    List<Event> event = EventController().GetEventsController() as List<Event>;
    return event;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 700,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: SfCalendar(
              view: CalendarView.month,
              dataSource: EventDatasource(_data()),
              initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
            ),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

eventDataSource.dart

class EventDatasource extends CalendarDataSource {
  EventDatasource(List<Event> appointments) {
    this.appointments = appointments;
  }
  Event getEvent(int index) => appointments![index];

  @override
  DateTime getStartTime(int index) {
    return getEvent(index).from;
  }

  @override
  DateTime getEndTime(int index) {
    // TODO: implement getEndTime
    return getEvent(index).to;
  }

  @override
  String getSubject(int index) {
    // TODO: implement getSubject
    return getEvent(index).title;
  }

  @override
  String? getNotes(int index) {
    // TODO: implement getNotes
    return getEvent(index).description;
  }
}

I got this error

_TypeError(type Future<List> is not a subtype of type List in type cast


uncompleted Future, make the _data method asynchronous and await for the result. await EventController().GetEventsController() ......;

Since you are passing as an argument to EventDataSource an property of type List<Event> then you need to do the following:
First change the _data() function from:
  _data() {
    List<Event> event = EventController().GetEventsController() as List<Event>;
    return event;
  }

to the following:
    Future<List<Event>> _data() async{
        return await EventController().GetEventsController();
  }

Use async/await since you need to wait for the data to be retrieved. Also since you are using async function, then the function can only return a value of type Future. Then inside the build() method, use the FutureBuilder widget to be able to get the result of this future and send it to the EventDataSource:
            Container(
            height: 700,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            width: double.infinity,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<Event>>(future: _data(), 
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return SfCalendar(
                  view: CalendarView.month,
                  dataSource: EventDatasource(snapshot.data),
                  initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
                ),
              }),
            )


For timestamp change your to Map model to this
Map<String, dynamic> ToMap() {
    return {
      "Id": Id,
      "user": user,
      "title": title,
      "description": description,
      "type": type,
      "from": from?.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      "to": to?.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    };
  }

and your fromMap() method to this
factory Event.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, String documentId) {
    return Event(
        Id: documentId,
        user: map["user"] as String,
        title: map["title"] as String,
        description: map["description"] as String,
        type: map["TYPE"] as String,
        from: map['from'] != null ? (map['from'] is Timestamp
          ? (map['from'] as Timestamp).toDate()
          : DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['from'] as int))
      : null,
        to: map['to'] != null ? (map['to'] is Timestamp
          ? (map['to'] as Timestamp).toDate()
          : DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['to'] as int))
      : null;
  }

You are getting this error because in your controller you are returning the Future of List.
Change your calendar widget like this
class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: EventController().GetEventsController(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              /// Depending on the state of our future,
              /// we return the appropriate ui elements
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
              } else {
                return Container(
                  height: 700,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: SfCalendar(
                    view: CalendarView.month,
                    dataSource: EventDatasource(snapshot.data),
                    initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

This would wrap your data in FutureBuilder and will wait for the Future to be completed first and then it would pass data in your EventDataSource
Always practice using a state management like GetX, Provider or Bloc to avoid these kind of problems in the UI elements

The following _TypeError was thrown building Calendar(dirty, state: _CalendarState#46634): type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Event>'
I change method to async and I got this error

@OulaR. DId you try this updated answer?

yes I tried but I got an empty array of data, I am trying to figure what is wrong in Controller , because I got this error:
Unhandled Exception: type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

I have updated the answer and have added the solution for the same

@OulaR. If this answer worked, can you please mark this as accepted. Thanks
